# BasicHTTPServer on Shared Hosting

Tags: python, basehttpserver

I am writing a foosball ladder for my office in Python, to be served on my HostGator shared hosting. I am very new to the language (C# guy by trade), but have gotten simple scripts to run on the server.

I used the example found at https://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer, modifying the server name to my domain and the port to a four digit number. I got HostGator support to open the corresponding outgoing port. I then chmodded the script with a+x and executed it. Success! The server ran and stayed up.

I tried to hit the server in various ways with no success.

- `http://mydomain.com/path/to/script`
- `http://mydomain.com:port/path/to/script`
- `http://mydomain.com:port`
- A GET request to the paths above.

What am I missing, server configuration-wise or code-wise, to successfully reach this BaseHTTPServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall not bind your server to 127.0.0.1 which is visible only from localhost, but better to `0.0.0.0` or to an IP of network interface on your server.

Start with `0.0.0.0` which will bind to all network interfaces.

If it does not help, than you shall check, if firewall allows access to given port.

Comment: It is most likely inbound ports being blocked by HostGator, so this advice definitely led me in the right direction.